# Javascript Regular Expression to match string unless preceeded by backslash

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I match U1234, but not \U1234 in Javascript?

I can't figure out how to not match the single backslash.
The closest I can get is:

```
\[\\]{0}U[0-9]{4}\b
```

But that doesn't work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Here's a tip I received earlier this year, use http://www.regexpal.com/ to test your regex.  Immediate results allow you to spend more time banging out the correct pattern. I love it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JavaScript definitely does not support lookbehind assertions. The next best way to get what you want, in my opinion, would be

```
(?:^|[^\\])(U[0-9]{4})
```

Explanation:

```
(?:          # non-capturing group - if it matches, we don't want to keep it
   ^         # either match the beginning of the string
   |         # or
   [^\\]     # match any character except for a backslash
)            # end of non-capturing group
(U\d{4})     # capturing group number 1: Match U+4 digits
```

Comment: oh, on a nit-picky point of note, if you want to match 0, 1, 2... 9 then you should use `[0-9]`. `\d` actually matches a lot more than 0-9.. there's a lot of unicode characters which are numbers in different character sets.

Comment: @nickf: `\d` only matches `[0-9]` in JavaScript--or it's supposed to, according to ECMA. Source: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-regex-and-unicode  Steve's `\d` test works correctly in every browser I have installed at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

`[^\\]U[0-9]{4}` or something along these lines. It will not match the sequence on the very beginning of subject string…

Comment: Escape that slash in the negated character set; it is currently escaping the closing bracket instead...  Try [^\\\]U[0-9]{4}

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately JS doesn't seem to support proper syntax for this, i.e. back assertion `/(?<!\\)U[0-9]{4}/`.

So you need to use:

```
/[^\\]U[0-9]{4}/
```

This is syntax for regexp literal. If you put regexp in a string, you have to escape backslashes again:

```
"[^\\\\]U[0-9]{4}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using lookbehind, but [JavaScript doesn't seem to support it](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind). Maybe you can match on U[0-9]{4}, find where the match is, and check the character to its left to see if it's a \ or not?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript's RegExp does not support negative look-behind assertions.  Ideas that propose you match only /[^\]U/ will match strings like "_U", so that's not the answer.  Your best bet is to use two regular expressions, the first to find all occurrences, then the second to filter the look-behind.

```
"\\U0000 U0000".match(/\\?U[0-9]{4}/g)
.filter(function (match) {
    return !/^\\/.test(match)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Ummm ... Is \^U[0-9]{4}\b works for you?